# Failed to resolve RXJava dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to run following project : https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/RxJava2-Android-Samples

The depencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0'
}
```

But I get following error.

> Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0
>   Show
>   in File
> Show in
>   Project Structure dialog

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: rebuild your project and try again

Comment: it is working for me...

Comment: ok I have not changed anything ... but all of a sudden it just works. ok.

Comment: thanks!!, Its working.Wondering why gradle was not syncing beforeRebuild? @Javacoder

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem with RxKotlin, IDE had Gradle in Offline mode. (*Settings-> Gradle -> Turn off offline mode*).

Also, I suggest checking, that you have the correct version [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.reactivex/rxkotlin).

It helped me to setup the [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin), because there was only `x.y.z.` version.

Working gradle import:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:2.0.0-RC1'
```